# AsyncTask onPostExecute stops executing after JSONObject

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, google-places-api

Good day!

I'm working with Google Maps, using their SDK and APIs (Place API, etc.). I faced the problem that when code gets to `val parentObject = JSONObject(result)` it stops executing the lines below. I debugged it and saw, that the URL and Maps I'm passing is ok, also I've already checked the URL outside Android Studio and it's ok, it gives me an array of JSONs. I don't understand why it just stops on that line. The code of the `AsyncTask` is below:

```
class MapsAsyncTasks : AsyncTask<Any, String, String>() {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
        private lateinit var url: String

        fun dataTransfer(map: GoogleMap, url: String): MapsAsyncTasks {
            val asyncTasks = MapsAsyncTasks()
            this.map = map
            this.url = url
            return asyncTasks
        }
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?): String? {
        try {
            val mUrl = URL(url)
            val httpURLConnection = mUrl.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            httpURLConnection.connect()

        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
        } catch (e: IOException) {
        }

        return url
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        try {
            if(result != null) {
                //It comes here
                val parentObject = JSONObject(result) //It do this line

                val resultsArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("candidates") //It does not executing this and other lines below

                for (i in 0 until resultsArray.length()) {
                    val jsonObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val locationObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")

                    val latitude = locationObject.getString("lat").toDouble()
                    val longitude = locationObject.getString("lng").toDouble()

                    val nameObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val name = nameObject.getString("name")
                    val latLng = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                    markerOptions.title(name)
                    markerOptions.position(latLng)

                    map.addMarker(markerOptions)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks for helping!

Comment: What about step-running that code in debugger?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it just stops with no information in logcat. The app doesn't crash and still working

Comment: Pretty unlikely that it just "stops". And I said - run your code in the debugger, plant a breakpoint and see step-by-step what is going on there. You did not do that yet.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yeah, sorry, you were right, it goes to the JSONException: https://imgur.com/a/bEGFrfv. I will try to find out what's happening. I can see this JSON in the browser but it goes to the error in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I remade this class making a new one (`PlacesAPI`) to separate AsyncTask and HTTP connection. Also, I added some more stuff to the new one, like `requestMethod`, `bufferReader`, etc. Instead of the new instance of the class (I used it to pass data), I made the parameters of the methods I needed to be used in the other classes. There is a code of a new class:

```
    class PlacesAPIs {

    lateinit var result: String

    fun getPlacesJSON(c: Context,
                      lat: Double,
                      lng: Double,
                      keyword: String,
                      type: String,
                      radius: Int,
                      language: String
    ): String {
        try {
            val key = c.resources.getString(R.string.google_maps_key)

            val urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?keyword=$keyword&type=$type&location=$lat,$lng&radius=$radius&language=$language&key=$key"
            val url = URL(urlString)
            val httpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
            httpURLConnection.requestMethod = "GET"
            httpURLConnection.doInput = true

            val br = httpURLConnection.inputStream.bufferedReader()
            result = br.use { br.readText() }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Places API:", "the APIM didn't get JSON")
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

And right now my `AsyncTask` looks like:

```
class MapsAsyncTasks(var c: Context, var lat: Double, var lng: Double, 
                     var keyword: String, var type: String, var radius: Int, 
                     var language: String, var map: GoogleMap) : AsyncTask<Any, String, String>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?): String? {
        return PlacesAPIs().getPlacesJSON(c, lat, lng, keyword, type, radius, language)
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        try {
            if(result != null) {

                val parentObject = JSONObject(result)
                Log.i("ParentObject:",parentObject.toString())
                val resultsArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("results")

                for (i in 0 until resultsArray.length()) {
                    val jsonObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val locationObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")

                    val latitude = locationObject.getString("lat").toDouble()
                    val longitude = locationObject.getString("lng").toDouble()
                    val name = jsonObject.getString("name")
                    val vicinity = jsonObject.getString("vicinity")
                    val latLng = LatLng(latitude, longitude)

                    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                    markerOptions.title(name)
                    markerOptions.position(latLng)
                    markerOptions.snippet(
                            vicinity
                    )
                    map.addMarker(markerOptions)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            //cathing error here
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked! Right now it shows me everything I need! Thanks to everybody for helping.

Answer (score 0):

There is no json array with "candidates" key in google Place Api response , please be sure that you deserialize the response correctly,

Comment: I can't be sure, but that what I've got using the URL: https://ibb.co/8MZh2ck
Are you sure there is no candidates key?

Also, that's not a problem, the problem is that code doesn't get to the candidates' line.